# find all occurrences of a regex as an array

Tags: sql, regex, substring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

have the following string (it's a salesforce query, but not important):

```
IF(OR(CONTAINS(EmailDomain,"yahoo"),CONTAINS(EmailDomain,"gmail"),
CONTAINS("protonmail.com,att.net,chpmail.com,smail.com",EmailDomain)),
"Free Mail","Business Email")
```

and I want to get an array of all substrings that are encapsulated between double quotes like so:

```
['yahoo',
'gmail',
'protonmail.com,att.net,chpmail.com,smail.com',
'Free Mail',
'Business Email']
```

in python I do:

```
re.findall(r'"(.+?)"', <my string>)
```

but is there a way to replicate this in Snowflake?

I've tried

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('IF(OR(CONTAINS(EmailDomain,"yahoo"),CONTAINS(EmailDomain,"gmail"),
CONTAINS("protonmail.com,att.net,chpmail.com,smail.com",EmailDomain)),
"Free Mail","Business Email")', '"(.+?)"') as emails;
```

but I get this:

```
"yahoo"),CONTAINS(EmailDomain,"gmail"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```sql
select split(trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '"([^"]+)"|.', '\\1|'),'\\|+','|'), '|'), '|');
```

*Details*:

- `regexp_replace(col, '"([^"]+)"|.', '\\1|')` - finds any strings between the closest double quotes while capturing the part inside quotes into Group 1, or matching any single char and replaces each match with Group 1 contents + `|` char (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5q9M04/1))
- `regexp_replace(...,'\\|+','|')` - this shrinks all consecutive pipe symbols into a single occurrence of a `|` char (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5q9M04/2))
- `trim(..., '|')` - removes `|` chars on both ends of the string
- `split(..., '|')` - splits the string with a `|` char.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktor's answer works great. I'm adding an alternate answer for anyone who needs to do this and their quoted strings may contain the pipe `|` character. Using the replacement method on strings containing pipe(s) will split the string into more than one array member. Here's a way (not the only way) to do it that will work in case the quoted strings could potentially contain pipe characters:

```
set col = $$IF(OR(CONTAINS(EmailDomain,"yahoo"),CONTAINS(EmailDomain,"gmail"),CONTAINS("protonmail.com,att.net,chpmail.com,smail.com",EmailDomain)),"Free Mail","Business Email | Other")$$;

create or replace function GET_QUOTED_STRINGS("s" string)
returns array
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$

var re = /(["'])(?:\\.|[^\\])*?\1/g;
var m;
var out = [];

do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        out.push(m[0].replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
    }
} while (m);

return out;

$$;

select get_quoted_strings($col);
```